# Autoalign changes width of my button

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm setting width for my button so that it's greater than text size - as on image below:

[image]

The width of it is 120px. My problem is that I have center vertical alignment for it so when I hit "update frames" then my button gets resized to it's minimum so that text fits the button as below:

[image]

I can't leave it that way because I've added frame programatically and it looks bad when it's so close to the text.

Is there any way to set some properties for xcode to stick to my width as oppose to auto-align it? I'd prefer to have it in xcode properties than in swift code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding a constraint to the width. You need to add a constraint to it, not change de width at the Size Inspector.

Select the element, click at the Pin option at the bottom bar, and set the width of your element. Update Frames and voilà.

[image]

Remember: when working with Auto Layout you cannot use any manual configuration (size, position, etc.) for that element, always use constraints or stack views.

[Apple documentation about Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)